# How to create a Postgresql generated column of type JSONB from columns of types JSONB, VARCHAR and DATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, generated-columns

I have a table test_data with 4 columns as shown below. I want to create a JSONB generated column with data from these columns. Below is what I have tried but keep on getting this error:

**ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable
SQL state: 42P17**

| name VARCHAR(50) | mixed_stuff JSONB | other_stuff JSONB | created TIMESTAMP | combined JSONB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |

```
CREATE TABLE test_data(name VARCHAR(50), mixed_stuff JSONB, other_stuff JSONB, created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE default(now() at time zone 'utc'));

ALTER TABLE test_data
add combined JSONB GENERATED ALWAYS AS (jsonb_build_object('name',name) || "mixed_stuff" || "other_stuff" || jsonb_build_object('created',created)) STORED;
```

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/264327 for sad news.

Answer (score 1):

Generated columns can only use immutable functions ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-generated-columns.htm)) while `jsonb_build_object()` is only marked as stable (run `\df+ jsonb_build_object` in psql to check).

As a workaround one can define a wrapper function marked as immutable (but beware of consequences depending on your usage scenario):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_build_object_imm(VARIADIC input anyarray) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(VARIADIC input)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

The reason why `jsonb_build_object()` is only stable because `to_json()` is only stable as many other type conversions -- compare with `json_object()` which takes only strings and is marked as immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Generated columns can only use immutable functions (docs) while jsonb_build_object is only marked as stable (run \df+ jsonb_build_object in psql). As a workaround one can define a wrapper marked as immutable:

CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_build_object_imm(VARIADIC input anyarray) RETURNS JSONB AS $$
SELECT jsonb_build_object(VARIADIC input)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE LEAKPROOF PARALLEL SAFE;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).